# Noobslide equivalent for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am looking for a jquery slideshow that similar to noobslide for mootool. Im looking to have text/img for each slide. Slide 1 has text1 and img 1. Slide 2 has text2 and img 2. They are static content.

Thanks.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Highslide](http://highslide.com). Its official site is plenty of links to examples.